# How to use additional attributes in Polymer core-item element?

Tags: polymer

In [this](http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-elements/demo.html#paper-checkbox) example core-item element is used as:

```
<core-item label="Checkbox" tag="paper-checkbox" url="../paper-checkbox/demo.html"></core-item>
```

Where are 'tag' and 'url' attributes documented i.e. where are they coming from?
(Confused because they are not in [core-item doc page](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-item) and neither core-item extends other element?!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from (or I might better say: it is used inside) the [sampler-scaffold.html](http://www.polymer-project.org/components/sampler-scaffold/sampler-scaffold.html).

The `<core-item>` tags are all wrapped inside one `<sampler-scaffold>` tag.

Inside the JavaScript functions, there is a function `parseLocationHash` (line 120-129)

```
parseLocationHash: function() {
  var route = window.location.hash.slice(1);
  for (var i = 0, item; item = this.$.menu.items[i]; i++) {
    if (item.getAttribute('tag') === route) {
      this.$.menu.selected = i;
      return;
    }
  }
  this.$.menu.selected = this.$.menu.selected || 0;
},
```

That function will get the currently selected item from the menu according to the current location hash. That's the way the currently selected `<core-item>` gets highlighted (via [`core-selector`](http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-selector/core-selector.html)).

In the `menuSelect` function (line 131-147) `tag` and `url` are used to change the `window location.hash` to the value of the `tag` attribute.

```
 this.item.tag = this.item.getAttribute('tag');
 var url = this.item.getAttribute('url');
 this.$.frame.contentWindow.location.replace(url);
 window.location.hash = this.item.tag;
```

So, the outside element of a `<core-item>` can access the inside elements, as they are child nodes. So they can be referenced within the outside/parent element.

If you're looking for the usage of an attribute, first have a look at the current elements source code. If it isn't referenced inside the template, you can be sure, it can't be accessed from any *deeper* element. So next, you might have look at the *higher* parent elements that contain the element you're interested in.

It isn't always easy to follow up the includes of Polymer elements, but perhaps this might help you to dive a bit deeper inside the structure.